# how to change simplebar color in angular

Tags: css, angular, simplebar

I implemented a simplebar in my angular application like the one in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simplebar-angular-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).

I tried to change the color following the documentation:

```
.simplebar-scrollbar::before {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But it did not work, is there any other way to change to color ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to change a component style from another component.
Or you change the global style or you change the component style like this:

```
::ng-deep .simplebar-scrollbar::before {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

A working example (changing from global style): https://stackblitz.com/edit/simplebar-angular-demo-2hcxnj?file=src/styles.css

Comment: Thank you I added !important and moved the code to the global style.css and it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

Use simple css like this:

```
.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical .simplebar-scrollbar:before {
    background-color: 'orange"
}
```

One of the samples uses a yellow/red gradient. You can achieve something similar like this:

```
.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical .simplebar-scrollbar:before {
       background-image: linear-gradient( yellow , red);
}
```

For more details, you can read this link
https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/issues/431